# Joomla multiple template not calling default files error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-template

I am creating a website which is running multiple templates. The default template has no issues but the other assigned templates are giving problems.

1) The internal templates are not calling the required asset files for components/modules/plugins. I am inserting the css and js files manually.

2) codes to show only some components on its home page or others in internal pages are not working in non default templates. Example code :

```
<?php if($this->countModules('travelnhomepagecheck')) { ?>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="travel_segment_threeimagerotator" style="xhtml" />
             <br />

             <jdoc:include type="component" />

        <?php } else { ?>

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2">
              <tr>
                <td width="65%" style="vertical-align:top;">
                    <jdoc:include type="component" />
                 </td>
                <td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top;">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="travel_segment_rightCol" style="xhtml" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>



        <?php } ?>
```

It only shows elements of the template's home page and not internal pages. Would appreciate any help in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that the asset files not beeing loaded? Maybe the other templates generating the HTML HEAD by a custom function and did not use the Joomla!-Head-Include-function.

Just look forward to a line in your templates like this:

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

This includes all the Meta Data, assets like css/js and so on. basically it imports the whole Joomla!HTML head. But some templates do that manually and then recently installed plugin-files wont be added automatically to the head-section.

Comment: I cant believe that after 7 years of making templates I missed that when it was the most obvious thing to check. That fixed the problem of having to pull the assets manually, however any idea on the other issues?

Comment: i dont understand the other problem. is it that you can only use default.php and no other layout file or what you meaning? can you explain please cos english isnt my native language.

Comment: no problem, ok the internal template works fine but what it does NOT do is that when in the internal template I want to show a set of modules on one link and not show those modules on another link, it doesnt work. Basically the internal module is unable to differentiate without what is the homepage and what are internal pages. I hope I was able to explain a little better. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Have you configured the Module itself to appear only on certain pages? you can do this in the module-advanced-parameters in your backend. Did you done this already?

Comment: yes i have , let me show you the page , [link(]http://www.oneworldnews.in/oneworldnews_joomla/index.php/news-categories-main/food)              if you click on the rotator below ..it should show some article, but it does not.. if you see the code above it should work ..but its not

Comment: Honestly i did not see any articles. Make sure you also include the content-component itself in your templates: `<jdoc:include type="component" />`. I dont understand whats your problem. you got a slider that link to articles with no content?